# Twitter Bootstrap Dismiss Button not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I am trying to use Twitter Bootstrap to create a website detailing the statistics of Minecraft servers, to make it easy for my users to know which server is online. However, when I use the alert component in Twitter Bootstrap, I cannot dismiss the alert. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

`<title>Dillon's Minecraft Servers</title>`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Vanilla</a></li>
    <li><a href="ftb.htm">Feed the Beast</a></li>
    <li><a href="bigdig.htm">Big Dig</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="hero-unit">
    <h2>Vanilla</h2>
    <p>The Vanilla server runs just plain Minecraft. It has some advanced features like Mob Arenas, anti-cheat, and MMO-like leveling.</p>
</div>

<div class="alert">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> This server is currently offline.
</div>
```

Comment: are you including the bootstrap JS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I found my problem. I forgot add the jquery script to the header. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a `<button>` rather than an `<a>`. That's what I did on my Bootstrap page as I was having a similar problem. Doesn't fix that problem but it is a valid way round

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
```

Comment: Damn, didn't see your answer. Ninja'd!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that jquery.min.js is loaded before button.js!